# nginx + uwsgi + django open uwsgi_params failed (13: permission denied)

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I tried to follow the nginx document here https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html. But stuck at `Configure nginx for your site`. I restarted nginx and it said "`nginx: [emerg] open() "/home/hanys/oligoweb/uwsgi_params" failed (13: Permission denied) in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/oligoweb.conf:19`".
My site.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /home/hanys/oligoweb/
module = oligoweb.wsgi
home = /home/hanys/.virtualenv/oligo-env
master = true
processes = 10
socket = /home/hanys/oligoweb/oligoweb.sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
daemonize   = /home/hanys/uwsgi-emperor.log
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
```

my site.conf in /etc/nginx/sites-available/

```
upstream django {
    server unix:///home/hanys/oligoweb/oligoweb.sock;
}

server {
    listen  80;
    server_name IP address here;
    charset     utf-8;
    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;
    # Django media and static files
    location /static {
        alias /home/hanys/oligoweb/static;
    }
    # Send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/hanys/oligoweb/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

uwsgi_params has 664 permission. I tried chmod 777 uwsgi_params but it didnt work.
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, `uwsgi_params` is already shipped with your Nginx, so all you need is `include uwsgi_params` (so it refers to `/etc/nginx/uwsgi_params` or similar).

If that is not the case, you will likely also need to give Nginx enough permissions to read the directory structure that file is in, not just the file itself.

Comment: Thank you! I change include     /home/hanys/oligoweb/uwsgi_params; to /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params and it works.